# Nginx - handling server response and initiating redirection from Nginx itself

Tags: url, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a proxy server. My API is deployed behind Nginx. One of the API returns "redirect:mail" as a response.

Can Nginx handle this response and initiate the redirection from Nginx itself instead of client/browser doing the redirection?

Comment: Where are you trying to redirect to?   A `mailto:` URL or a web mail client?

Comment: Am hitting API-1 and it return the url of API2. Can Nginx redirect me to API2? Here "redirect:mail" is the response returned by a Spring rest API. Instead if browser performing the redirection, can Nginx do the redirection even before the response goes to Broswer?

Comment: What is the URL of the other API?

Comment: What code are you using to hit this API?  JavaScript in the browser?  XMLHTTPRequest?